# Running a script only for dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a list of 10 items with a particular class. when the page scrolls to the end, the following 10 items are loaded.

I want to bind an event only for items that are loaded dynamically rather than for 10 indoor items.

My problem is that the items look exactly the same, I can not change any class or anything else.
any solution?

Comment: unclear what you are doing to bind. Show us code that does not work.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Set` containing first ten objects at the start of the page. Later bind event only to elements that are not in the set.

```js
var s = new Set();
document.querySelectorAll('.aaa').forEach(el=>s.add(el));

setTimeout(function() {
  ex.innerHTML += '<span class="aaa">aaa</span>';
  ex.innerHTML += '<span class="aaa">aaa</span>';
  ex.innerHTML += '<span class="aaa">aaa</span>';
  ex.innerHTML += '<span class="aaa">aaa</span>';

  document.querySelectorAll('.aaa').forEach(el=> {
    if (!s.has(el)) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('You clicked me');
      });
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.aaa {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<span class="aaa">aaa</span>
<div id = "ex"></div>
```

Only last 4 elements have added click event listener.

Comment: There are better ways of doing this than having to loop every single time.

Comment: Yes, you can add custom class to objects you don't want to attach eventListener to, and use `:not` selector for example. That would be much faster(and work in all browsers).

Comment: @agsigma - i wrote i cant change or add classes, the items are just the same

Comment: @BIBI yes you can add classes... you do it when you select the elements and attach the click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is how you deal with adding events to dynamic content. Since you did not show actual code, you get a generic answer.

```
$(document).on("click", ".yourClass", function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

This way you do not have to bind events every time the content is loaded. It will just listen on a parent element for the click.

It would be better to change `document` to a parent element that contains all of the elements you are listening to the click event on.